# integer to byte without using struct in python

Tags: python, struct, integer, byte

I need to use an embedded system running Python 1.5.2+ (!!!) with very few modules.
And there is no "struct" module usable...
Here is the list of usable modules :

```
marshal
imp
_main_
_builtin_
sys
md5
binascii
```

Yes that's it, no struct module...

So, I need to create a 4 bytes representation of an unsigned short integer to send to serial...

With struct :

```
date = day + month * 32 + (year - 2000) * 512
time = 100 * hour + minute
data = struct.pack(b'HH', date, time)
```

date on 2 bytes time on 2 bytes and everybody's happy...

But without using 'struct' module, how can I do that?

Comment: I.. don't see how you could do that without at least ctypes available. Note that `strcut` itself is implemented in c for exactly that reason. If you can't write a c module yourself you're out of luck I'd think.

Comment: @Voo: That's perfectly doable with plain Python

Comment: @Niklas TJDs answer creates a `PyObject*` though, how do you get the pointer to the start of the actual data?

Comment: @Voo: It creates a byte string, exactly like struct would

Comment: @Voo, no my answer creates a string with binary data in it, just like struct.pack

Comment: @TJD Yeah but isn't a string a `PyObject*` itself? How do we know that start of `PyObject == usable data`?

Comment: @Voo: I have no idea what you're talking about. Sean's answer, for example, produces the exact same output that OP's code would. Why do you even mention `PyObject`? We are only talking about pure Python here.

Comment: @Niklas Got somewhat confused with ctypes, i.e. that you can't pass  a python string object to a c function expecting a `char*` arg.

Comment: @Voo: Of course you can't, but then again, you can't call *any* C function without ctypes, so that can't be OP's intention.

Comment: @Niklas Yep as I said confused - I think the heat's affecting me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete translation for you

Before

```
>>> import struct
>>> day = 1; month = 2; year = 2003
>>> hour = 4; minute = 5
>>> date = day + month * 32 + (year - 2000) * 512
>>> time = 100 * hour + minute
>>> data = struct.pack(b'HH', date, time)
>>> data
'A\x06\x95\x01'
>>> data.encode("hex")
'41069501'
```

And after

```
>>> data2 = chr(date & 0xFF) + chr((date >> 8) & 0xFF) + chr(time & 0xFF) + chr((time >> 8) & 0xFF)
>>> data2
'A\x06\x95\x01'
>>> data2.encode("hex")
'41069501'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot fot this solution too !

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
x = 0xabcd

packed_string = chr((x & 0xff00) >> 8) + chr(x & 0x00ff)
```

Comment: I think example code that would convert date/time to the specified output string would be more beneficial to OP.

Comment: @SeanJohnson, I don't intend to write code for OP.  The crux of the question is 'how do I replace struct.pack'?  You can easily use my mechanism to implement your own struct.pack and use that for whatever purposes you may have.

Comment: @NiklasB. Only because its highly portable(to any language) and relies on no modules other than \_\_builtin\_\_.chr that has been around a very long time(forever?) ... bytes(x) is good but wont work for OP... on a side note your solution was good too... just less general

Comment: @Joran: I don't know what you're even talking about. lists, `map` and `join` has been around for at least as long as `chr` (in fact they have both been part of Python 1.0). Care to explain what you mean by "less general"? In fact I like to think of higher-order operations on being *more* general. Also, did you just imply that "correct" == "general" == "portable"?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by passing a list of the bytes to bytes():

```
data=bytes([date%256,date//256,time%256,time//256])
```

Comment: bytes is a recent addition to builtins, not applicable to this question

Comment: @TJD: The idea of creating a list of bytes is more elegant than manual bit-fiddling, though. The joining is more or less cosmetics